# Differences between Protocol.__call__ vs Callable?

Tags: python, typing, callable

I have a function

```py
def run_thing(cb: Callback) -> Result:
  w: Widget = make_widget()
  res: Result = cb(w)
  return res
```

I can imagine two ways to define the Callback type.

```py
# Option 1: Callable
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#annotating-callables
Callback = typing.Callable[[Widget],Result]
```

```py
# Option 2: Protocol
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol
class Callback(typing.Protocol):
  def __call__(self,w: Widget) -> Result:
    ...
```

What are the nuances to consider in the decision between the two above type definitions?

Comment: I'm using `typing.Protocol` when there are variadic/keyword-only parameters or when I need to specify names of the parameters (since `typing.Callable` can't express that), so in the given case `typing.Callable` is good enough, but for `typing.Protocol` to be equivalent we need to use positional-only delimiter (available in [`python3.8`+](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/)) like `def __call__(self, w:Widget, /)->Result:`

Comment: I don't understand negative vote on this question! Personally I will go on the typing protocol option since you can handle more options as defining extra methods that the protocol may needs or setting positional arguments or keyword arguments only, finally (just personal opinion) I think makes it more clearer code.